# Azure Function on Linux Breaks Node function requiring Node v12 when Deployed from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a Nodejs Azure Function using a timer trigger. It uses some modern Javascript syntax (await, flatMap, etc) that is supported in Node v12.

I've deployed my infrastructure with Terraform and specified the linuxFxVersion as "node|12". So far so good. When I deploy my code from the Azure DevOps using the built-in AzureFunctionApp@1 task, it will cause the function to deploy a new image that is running Node v8. This causes my function to break.

Here is the release definition:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy: XXXXXXXXX'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'XXXXXXXXX'
    appType: functionAppLinux
    appName: 'XXXXXXXXX'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_XXXXXXXXX/drop/out.zip'
    runtimeStack: 'DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-node8:2.0'
    configurationStrings: '-linuxFxVersion: node|12'
```

You can see I explicitly try to force the linuxFxVersion to remain 'node|12' in the release.

In the release logs, you can watch the release try to set the configuration for linuxFxVersion 2x, once to the wrong image, and the second time to "node|12".
[image: deployment task logs]

After I release the code, the function will still run, but when I print the node version it shows version 8 and fails at runtime when it hits the unsupported syntax.

If I re-run my terraform script, it will show me that the linuxFxVersion for my function app is now set to 'DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-node8:2.0' and it sets it back to "node|12". After that runs, my function now works. If I update my code and deploy again, it breaks again in the same way.

What is even more baffling to me is that this is a v3 function app, which in theory does not support Node v8 at all.

Am I missing something obvious here or is the Function App release task just broken for Linux Functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing up this whole big question, and proof reading it... I noticed this little snippet in the release task YAML (which I hadn't seen before today as it's a release and uses the AzDO GUI for editing):

`runtimeStack: 'DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-node8:2.0'`

It turns out, if you specify the stack as 'JavaScript' (the options are .NET and JavaScript) the task sets the "runtimeStack" to that string. Which is what gets set in the linuxFxVersion setting on the Function App. Even if you override that setting in the configuration settings.

The fix is to leave the Runtime field blank and then it will respect your settings. Awesome.